# CakePHP3: How to get associated in beforeDelete() callback?

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x

In a `beforeDelete()` callback, I need informations contained in associated but I cannot find how to get it. My callback is below in AgpoiaudiosTable.php:

```
public function beforeDelete($event, $entity, $options) {

    $agpoiaudio = $this->Agpoiaudios->get($entity->id, [
            'contain' => 'Agpois.AgThemes.Sites'
    ]);

    if ($agpoiaudio != null) {
        ...
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But `$this->Agpoiaudios->get()` causes Cake to send me the following error:

`Error: Table "App\Model\Table\AgpoiaudiosTable" is not associated with "Agpoiaudio"`

Do I really have to load associated before calling `$this->Agpoiaudios->delete()` to find it in `$entity`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to load associated data before calling `Table::delete()`, that's not what the error indicates. What it *does* indicate, is that `Agpoiaudio` is not associated with `Agpoiaudio`, ie you cannot access `$this->Agpoiaudio` in an instance of `Agpoiaudio`.

So, since you're already in an instance of `Agpoiaudio`, just call `Table::get()` directly, ie

```
$agpoiaudio = $this->get($entity->id, [
    'contain' => 'Agpois.AgThemes.Sites'
]);
// ...
```